# Android Smack giving timeoutexception when joining MultiUserChat

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, multiuserchat

I am trying to join a MultiUserChat using Smack on Android. Currently I can chat 1-on-1 perfectly fine, and I am connected to the server as I show online. I followed the examples provided [here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html).

I have the following code to join a `MultiUserChat` (MUC).

```
final XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
        .setUsernameAndPassword(user.getUsername(), user.getJabberPassword())
        .setServiceName("app.buur.nu")
        .setHost("app.buur.nu")
        .setPort(5222)
        .build();

AbstractXMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);

String room = "testroom";
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(room + "@groups.app.buur.nu"); 
try {
    muc.join(user.getUsername(), null, null, connection.getPacketReplyTimeout());
} catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But this gives me 
`org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): testroom@groups.app.buur.nu/test, StanzaTypeFilter: org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence).`

I tried increasing the timeout to 10000 ms, but I still get a timeout. What could be wrong here? Creating 1-on-1 chats works fine and `connection.isConnected())` returns True...

---

So it turns out that I get an error

`<presence to="app.buur.nu/7c65be6" id="lgcSp-4" type="error"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack" ver="os2Kusj3WEOivn5n4iFr/ZEO8ls="/><error code="401" type="auth"><not-authorized xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></presence>`

Basically, the authentication is not completed when I am attempting to join the room. Can a listener be added to receive an update when the authentication has been completed? I saw https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/SASLAuthentication.html#authenticate%28java.lang.String,%20javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler%29 but implementing my own authentication mechanism seems a little overkill...

Isn't there a `onAuthenticationCompletedListener` or something?

Comment: A stanza trace would be insightful. Have a look at https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/How-to-ask-for-help,-report-an-issue-and-possible-solve-the-problem-yourself

Comment: @Flow will update my post

Comment: The presence is missing the 'from' attribute. Which implementation does provide the MUC service?

Comment: I use openfire as the XMPP server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there is no need to implement the SASLMechanism, you can do the following:

```
connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {

        }

        @Override
        public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
            joinMUCRooms();
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {

        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {

        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {

        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {

        }
    });
```

The error no longer shows now, while keeping the code "fairly" clean.

Comment: I did the same as you said above but still getting the same exception. Anything else I can do to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does the room exist? If not then you need to create it first, using `create()` and sending a instant form. You should also report to the openfire developers that the MUC error presence is missing the 'from' attribute.